# Redis data type to keep view count of posts

Tags: redis

I want to keep the viewCount of posts in Redis, While I'm not sure which of the following approaches is more performant:

1. For **each** post have a redis **unique key** and store the viewCount as **value** for it:
   For example have the key `viewCount856` with value 1000 which means the viewCount of post with id 856 is 1000.
2. Have a redis **sorted set (zset)** as described [here](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro) and use each postId as score and the associated viewCount as value for that score. For example have a zset called `viewCount` and add all the posts and their viewCount to this set having their id as score.
3. Any other data type that is performant for this use-case and I hadn't thought of.

I would appreciate any other suggestions that will help implementing this in the best way.

Comment: do you only need a total view count or also time based data to show the view per hour or per day?

Comment: @GuyKorland I only need the total view count in cache. As I'm storing the records of time based data in db, Just to persist them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... implementing this in the best way

There is no "best way" - it is always a tradeoff so you need to pick what's important to you. Important means how you'll be accessing the data - with approach #1 you'd only be able to fetch a single counter, whereas with #2 you'd be able to use ranges.

If you don't need ranges, I'd go with #1 and consider using Hashes to optimize memory consumption (see https://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization#using-hashes-to-abstract-a-very-memory-efficient-plain-key-value-store-on-top-of-redis for the details). That will give you constant time access.

However, if ranges are required (e.g. top-n viewed posts), a Sorted Set will do nicely. The tradeoff here is more memory and O(n*logn) access.

Comment: Also if you want to do distinct counting, you can try HyperLogLog.